# Web scraping selector for specific element

Tags: css, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am new to web scraping and I'm trying to use Scrapy to scrape the Release Date for the following website: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/?ref_=adv_li_tt

This is the selector I am using:

```
//a[contains(@class,'ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link')]/text()
```

It returns too many elements and I just want the release data string.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and scrape, scraper, scraped) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish, or fighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select more specific and get only the text of release date adjust your path like this:

```
//li[contains(@data-testid,'title-details-releasedate')]//li/a/text()
```

It will select the `<li>` that contains the attribute `data-testid` with value `title-details-releasedate`. Cause these contains two `<a>` it focus on the `<a>` that is contained in another `<li>`